# Apex Data loader - Error java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 32-bit SW T libraries on 64-bit JVM

Tags: java, eclipse, salesforce, unsatisfiedlinkerror, apex

I am trying  to run apex data loader downloaded and installed from my SalesForce account. But when I try to run the jar from command prompt with this command

```
java -jar dataloader-29.0.0-uber.jar
```

I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 32-bit SWT libraries on 64-bit JVM
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:21)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:138)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.ui.LoaderWindow.<init>(LoaderWindow.java:83)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.controller.Controller.createAndShowGUI(Controller.java:207)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.DataLoaderRunner.main(DataLoaderRunner.java:45)
```

I am not even running from eclipse , but why I see below line in the exception ??

```
 at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:263)
```

Mine is 64 bit Windows 8 OS. How to run it ?

Comment: Hi @sandra, looks like you may have already gotten an answer, but so you're aware there is a new stackexchange site specific to Salesforce at salesforce.stackexchange.com. Come join the community over there! :) As a reference there are about 4x the questions on the new stackexchange as compared to SO and a lot more active participants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse is not involved, but SWT is, which is the GUI framework used by Eclipse (and therefore included in the package name). It seems like that particular jar is 32-bit only, so check whether there's a 64-bit version of it, or download a 32-bit JVM and run the jar with that.